# How to stop Wordpress trying to update my theme with a theme on Wordpress.org

Tags: php, wordpress, function, themes, updates

I have had a personal/custom theme named "Chameleon" for over 1 year. As of yesterday, I get a notification in Wordpress to update it to the latest version. Out of curiosity, I clicked it (knowing it was not my update).

**Wordpress replaced my theme with a Wordpress.org theme** named "Chameleon".

I have googled this issue, and it appears Wordpress has no intention of fixing this ridiculous bug. The issue seems to have been brought up 9 years ago.
I do not know how this has only become apparent now. I have been using creating Wordpress sites for clients for 9 years and never ever seen anything like this.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Is there a function I can add that stop Wordpress looking for an update on Wordpress.org for just my custom themes?

A fix like changing the name in the style.css and folder is not going to cut it.

Comment: "A fix like changing the name in the style.css and folder is not going to cut it." Why not? What's wrong with that?

Comment: Because my theme is used on multiple client websites. And what happens when another theme gets uploaded on Wordpress.org with the same name. It seems ridiculous that Wordpress thinking my theme is owned by someone else based on a folder name and not something truly unique.

Comment: That is basically allowing someone to look at the source code of any Wordpress frontend, get the wp-content/theme/foldername and create a theme, upload it to Wordpress.org and highjack their theme! (like what has happened to mine)

Comment: Well, yeah, I get that. Nothing you can do about it though, except maybe create a petition in wordpress.org to fix that and hope that someday someone will actually do something about it. For the time being, the easiest & fastest way to prevent this from happening is renaming the folder to something unique to your site (eg. `my_site_chameleon`) and be done with it.

Comment: Seems crazy! and strange that only now it has appeared after all this time. Is there not a function I can add that stops Wordpress doing this?

Comment: Have you tried [this](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/179684/135534) already?

Answer (score 2):

Try in functions.php:

```
//Disable automatic WordPress theme updates
add_filter( 'auto_update_theme', '__return_false' );
```

Or All updates in your wp-config.php file:

```
define( 'AUTOMATIC_UPDATER_DISABLED', true );
```

[Read more](https://wordpress.org/support/article/configuring-automatic-background-updates/)

Also you can try this plugin - [Disable All WordPress Updates](https://ru.wordpress.org/plugins/disable-wordpress-updates/). Inside it chose option "Disable All Theme Updates".

Answer (score 0):

This fixed my error in Chameleon:

custom_functions.php (epanel/custom_functions.php)  in line 786

```
}

$last_update->last_checked = time();
set_site_transient( 'et_update_themes', $last_update );

return $update_transient;
```